# Permissions for Sharepoint 2016 Public site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem

My client's system admin have created a public SharePoint site for their Sharepoint 2016 (on prem)
How do I grant read access to external users and contribute rights to internal users?

Comment: By external users you mean anonymous users?

Answer (score 1):

For external users, you could enable anonymous access in SharePoint 2016 site.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Enable Anonymous Access for SharePoint 2010/2013/2016. It also can work in SharePoint 2016.](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010)

For internal users, you could grant the internal users with contribution permission in the site permission.

Updated:

To sync users from AD to SharePoint, you should start a full user profile synchronization in the user profile service application.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Start profile synchronization manually in SharePoint Server.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/start-profile-synchronization-manually)

And then run the two timer jobs “User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint full synchronization” and “User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint quick synchronization”.

Go to Central Administration->Monitoring->Review job definitions-> Find “User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint full synchronization” and “User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint quick synchronization” and click “Run Now”.

Comment: Thank you Amy - but when I want to add the internal users in the site permission, it does not pick up the names from the Active Directory?  Do I need to change a setting somewhere to sync that public site with the AD?

Comment: I have updated my reply

Comment: Hi Amy - I've followed your steps, but the AD users still does not show when I want to add them in the public site settings as users that can contribute.